# Resize modulo N

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have pictures in various heights and need to resize them to the nearest height modulo N.

Example:

Original file:

```
1200x956
```

I need `h%N = 0 with N = 20`. Then the expected output is:

```
1200x960
```

Because 960%20 = 0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by a simple [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script. For example, take the following logic flow.

- Iterate over a list of all images
- Capture current image width
- While NOT a modulus of 20

  - Increment if modulus over 10
  - Decrement of modulus is under 10
  - Repeat as needed
- `mogrify` original image with adjusted width value.

```sh
files="first_image.jpg second_image.jpg"

for file in $files
do
    # Capture original width
    let width=$(identify -format '%w' $file)
    # Identify offset
    let offset=$(expr $width % 20)
    # Repeat until offset is 0
    while [ $offset -ne 0 ]
    do
        # Increment/Decrement width as needed
        if [ $offset -lt 10 ]
        then
            width=$(($width-1))
        else
            width=$(($width+1))
        fi
        # Update offset
        offset=$(expr $width % 20)
    done
    # Overwrite image with newly found width
    mogrify -resize ${width}x $file
done
```

**Edit**

Of corse the above example can be simplified. Perhaps even calculate the evaluation of `expr $width % 20`.

```sh
files="first_image.jpg second_image.jpg"

delta() {
    mod=$(expr $1 % 20)
    [[ $mod -lt 10 ]] && echo $(expr $mod \* -1) || echo $(expr 20 - $mod)
}

for file in $files
do
    let width=$(identify -format %w $file)
    let height=$(identify -format %h $file)
    let new_width=$(($width + $(delta $width)))
    let new_height=$(($height + $(delta $height)))
    mogrify -resize "${new_width}x${new_height}" $file
done
```